# Prove the interval $I$ is connected and closed

Tags: general-topology

Given a half-open and half-closed interval $(0,1]$, suppose a sequence $\{x_n\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ is in this interval and satisfies $\lim_{n\to\infty} x_n=0$. $f$ is a continuous function defined on $(0,1]$ that maps the sequence $\{x_n\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ to another sequence $\{f(x_n)\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$. Set the limit of $\{f(x_n)\}$ $a\in\mathbb{R}$, $\lim_{n\to\infty}f(x_n)=a$. Let $I$ be the subset of $\mathbb{R}$ that it is consisted of all points $a$ i.e. $I=\{a\mid a=\lim_{n\to\infty}f(x_n)\}$. I want to prove that when $I$ is not empty set, then it is a connected and closed set.

Before the question I solved one pre-question that is, $f(x)=\sin\frac{1}{x}$ and find interval $I$. I got the result $I=[-1,1]$ which is a closed and connected set. So I think it only needs to show $I$ is a closed interval, but I cannot think out how to prove it. Maybe I should asuume $I$ is an open set and try to lead the contradiction.

Comment: $f$ is continuous where? In your example, $f$ is not continuous at $x=0$, which is quite relevant for this problem. If $f$ is continuous at $x=0$, the result will (by definition) be $I = [f(0), f(0)]$, i.e. a single point.

Comment: "open set" is not the opposite of "closed set", so assuming that a set is open and getting a contradiction does not prove that the set is closed.

Comment: @jjagmath You're right. So I decide to prove it directly, how about proving its closure is the subset of itself?

Comment: @DominikS $f$ is only defined continuous on $(0,1]$.

Comment: Please include this in the question.

Comment: The claim is not true. There is nothing preventing $I$ from being not closed, or not connected for that matter. Take the sequence $x_n = 2^{-n}$ and the function $f (x) = x$. The limit of the sequence $\{ f (x_n) \}$ is $0$, as you can easily check. Take $I = (-1, 1)$, which is certainly not closed, but it (1) is a subset of $\mathbb{R}$, (2) contains $a = 0$, and (3) is not empty. Are you sure your description of $I$ is accurate?

Comment: @K.Jiang I checked my question and editted again.

Comment: Here's what you want to do. You want to prove that if there's a sequence $a_i$ such that $\lim f(a_i)=a$, and a sequence $b_i$ such that $\lim f(b_i)=b$, and if $c$ is a number between $a$ and $b$, then there's a sequence $c_i$ such that $\lim f(c_i)=c$. That will prove you have an interval. To prove that interval is closed, you need to show that if $\lim r_i=r$, and if for each $i$ there is a sequence $s_{ij}$ such that $\lim_j f(s_{ij}=r_i$, then there's a sequence $t_k$ such that $\lim f(t_k)=r$.

Comment: Making any progress, Cunyi?

Comment: @GerryMyerson I was doing other types of problems in topology and didn't make progress on it, maybe I will return to it after few days.